# Unable to add users to alpha testing

Tags: actions-on-google

I've been using actions on alpha testing and had few users added and try it on their devices. now recently I am trying to add users and when I click save after adding an email all the entered emails disappear when I return to deploy page and then revisiting the alpha testing page. is it a bug or some permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

I received the following message from Google:

> Our internal team has identified the bug and fix the issue. Please try
> to reload Actions Console and you should be able to view the alpha
> tester list as before. If you continue to have the same problem,
> deleting your browser's cache should help.

In my case, it works.